# How to implement discontinuous action for reinforcement learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I am training a RL agent to operate a device and the agent has a continuous action space (DDPG).

The device can be off or operate in a voltage range 6-12 V.

- If a naively map 6-12 V to the interval [-1, 1] then I remove the option switch of the device.
- If I map 0-12V to the interval [-1, 1] half the range will not be used and makes the learning problem harder.
- I can introduce a discontinuity and say that the action values in the range [-1, -0.9) turns of the device off
- Add additional action variables that is on/off

Is there any standard way to approach this problem? Any reference to where a similar situation has been tackled would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a reference, but the last option (a binary on/off output, combined with a continuous voltage ouput which is only used if the **on** action is taken) is the most reasonable.

In particular if the system is such that you either want the voltage off or as high as possible (both are fine), then a separate on/off binary variable allows you to learn this sort of "multimodal" behavior, whereas your other solutions would make it difficult.

Comment: I went with mapping [-1, -0.9) to off and [-0.9, 1] to the voltage range and I managed to get an agent working for my problem but having two variables is probably cleaner!